# Is it perfectly legal to declare a pure virtual function twice (in two classes in an hierarchy)

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

The question's title is pretty clear. Here's what I mean by example:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class C: public B
{
public:
    virtual void f() {}
};
```

Comment: @Simple - some quote from the standard or something?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov if he had, it were aAnswer and not a comment :P

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a down-vote, but..

Comment: I don't see it as well, In my view a good question.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but I believe that omitting the declaration will provide the same behavior.

Comment: @KirilKirov there's nothing special going on. In `B` you are overriding `A::f` but declaring it pure virtual, so `B` is still abstract. Theres a small difference in that calling `B::f()` from `C::f` would actually call `B::f` whereas if you didn't override it in `B` it would call `A::f`.

Comment: @Simple - thanks, I think exactly the same, but I wasn't sure about this. I still hope for some kind of proof, but I doubt there's anything about this in the standard, unfortunately.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I think there is no need to address this specific case because is captured by the general case.

Comment: Considering how virtual methods are (usually) implemented, this should not cause any problem: the virtual method table of `B` will just contain a null pointer for `f` instead of containing... a null pointer (well, probably not a null pointer, but you get my point). Of course, this is not a definitive answer since it assumes a particular implementation, but I don't really see why the standard would disallow such a thing. This is just an opinion though, I don't have time to dig through the standard to find the relevant quotes.

Comment: @remyabel - by the way, I didn't down-vote your answer, although it didn't help me.

Comment: @LucTouraille - thanks for the shared thoughts, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is legal because there are not the same functions at all. The `B::f()` function is an overriding of `A::f()`. The fact that `f()` is virtual in both cases is not entering into account.

Comment: I don't really get your point. It's _pure_ virtual, without implementation. And it's overriding, not overloading, which is significant here.

Comment: Yes, I meant overriding. Sorry. But, maybe I missed your point... :-/. For me, there is no possible confusion based on functions respective types. So, they are not "the same".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly legal.

In most situations the declaration on f() in B doesn't change the meaning of the program in any way, but there's nothing wrong with a little redundancy.

Recall that the "= 0" means only that the class may not be instantiated directly; that all pure virtual function must be overridden before an object can be instantiated.

You can even provide a definition for a pure virtual function, which can be called on an instance of a subclass. By explicitly declaring B::f(), you leave open the option of giving a definition for B::f().

Answer (score 1):

These three f() functions are difference but it is legal to declare same virtual function in two class because f() in A is overridden in F() in B.
It function call depends on the class object.

so as according to above code , you do not have permission to create an instance of class A and B. hence every time the function define inside class C will be called.